# Antlr4 getParent Current Context

Tags: antlr4

I have a grammer snippet like this

```
expr: left=expr '=' right=expr #exprassign
    | atom #expratom
    ;

atom: TEXT
    | ID 
    ;

 TEXT:  '\''(.)*?'\'';
 ID:[A-Z]+;
```

In my visitor method

> visitExprAtom()

How can I find getparent context which is current. Lets say my method works under left side say it fromleft other is fromright

I need to change my approaches when I learn where does it come from fromleft or fromright

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Let's assume I got a code snippet.

```
var varcompany='C1';// Creates an variable named company initialated C1 

SELECT * FROM TABLE 
 WHERE COMPANY = varcompany; //COMPANY ='C1'
```

Above expr grammar is parsing for COMPANY = varcompany

this approach my parser think for COMPANY as a variable and tries to find in my map for it. Or I use atom expression other Dsl scenerios and I need its acting differently. on SQL it must return like ***'C1'*** but other scenerios it must return ***C1***

Comment: Sorry, your description + question doesn't make much sense to me. Can your reformulate it to better explain what you are after? You obviously want to do something with the parent of a parser rule context, but what?

Comment: @MikeLischke For your demand I edited it.